# What's the point for this variable data?

Tags: timer, driver, linux-device-driver

I know with `struct timer_list` i can create a timer

there're some file within this structure there's a field called data `unsigned long data;`

What's the point for this variable `data`?

P.d if someone can explain how to work all this structure `timer_list` at low level!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is passed as the argument to the function registered with the timer. The below lines are from LDD3. Much more details can be found on LDD3 Chapter 7 http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch07.pdf

```
The expires field represents the jiffies value when the timer is expected to run; at that time, the function function is called with data as an argument.
```